# How do I reference a string as the root node of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I've produced the following tree plot:

> [image]

But I want the root to be $a$, which is a string. I looked at the documentation, it says:

> [image]

So it seems it's very easy, we just write something like:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 5, 7 -> 8}, Automatic, 1, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

Where we switch `1` by `"a"` but this is not working. So how do I reference a string as the root node of a graph?

Comment: try `Table[TreePlot[{"a" -> "d", "a" -> "f", "a" -> "h", "b" -> "f", "c" -> "h", 
 "d" -> "e", "g" -> "h"}, Automatic, root, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic], {root, {"a", "e"}}] `?

Comment: @kglr Yes! I don't know why but this way of using `Table[]` sounds very weird to me. I'm used to `Table[something, {x,a,b}]`.

Comment: @kglr To do what I want, I'd just need to write: `Table[TreePlot[{"a" -> "d", "a" -> "f", "a" -> "h", "b" -> "f", 
   "c" -> "h", "d" -> "e", "g" -> "h"}, Automatic, root, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic], {root, {"a"}}]` Can't we make it without using `Table[]` ?

Comment: just use `TreePlot[{"a" -> "d", "a" -> "f", "a" -> "h", "b" -> "f",     "c" -> "h", "d" -> "e", "g" -> "h"}, Automatic, "a",    VertexLabels -> Automatic]`. In the example, `Table` was used to show two cases with different roots.

Comment: @kglr Damn, it wasn't working in my code. But the other code was running perfectly, now I tried in my code and it is working (???). [Just as a god-fearing peasant in the middle ages](https://youtu.be/dywM446-vcE), I'll just try to cope with this by assuming it was a message of God or something. 

Answer (score 3):

```
edgelist = {"a" -> "d", "a" -> "f", "a" -> "h", "b" -> "f", "c" -> "h", 
   "d" -> "e", "g" -> "h"};

TreePlot[edgelist, Automatic, "a",    VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
TreePlot[edgelist, Automatic, "e",    VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

If the vertex list of your tree is `Range[8]`:

```
edgelist2 = {1 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 5, 7 -> 8};

TreePlot[edgelist2, Automatic, 1, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

you can label the vertices using `vlabels`:

```
vlabels = CharacterRange["a", "h"];

TreePlot[edgelist2, Automatic, 1, VertexLabels -> {i_ :> vlabels[[i]]}]
```

[image]